# get 3 different value using one script

Tags: c#

I want to get this 3 value using  1 script to use it in c# code

```
select COUNT(clos.ticket_cp) as clos from clos where CONVERT(date,date) = CONVERT(date,GETDATE())

select COUNT(en_cours.ticket_cp) as encour from en_cours where CONVERT(date,date) = CONVERT(date,GETDATE())

select COUNT(gele.ticket_cp) as gele from gele where CONVERT(date,date) = CONVERT(date,GETDATE())
```

Comment: If you want solution using `c#` then tag `c#`, don't put irrelevant tags.

Comment: "I want" isn't a question, it's a demand. if you have a question, ask one, but please don't demand that the *volunteers* here do the work for you. Especially as you've shown no effort to solve the problem yourself, or described the problems you faced when trying to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL`

```
select 'clos' as name, COUNT(clos.ticket_cp) as counte 
from clos where CONVERT(date,date) = CONVERT(date,GETDATE())
union all
select 'encour',COUNT(en_cours.ticket_cp)  
from en_cours where CONVERT(date,date) = CONVERT(date,GETDATE())
union all
select 'gele',COUNT(gele.ticket_cp) as gele 
from gele where CONVERT(date,date) = CONVERT(date,GETDATE())
```

Comment: thank you but   i want a table with 2 column (name , counte ) in the name would be ("clos , gele , encour) and in the counte would be the count of every one of them

Comment: @PØlirântéÑêllÿ, I've edited my answer - you can check now

Answer (score 0):

Option 1

```
Create table #temp (
 Name    varchar(20),
 Count     int
  ) 

Insert into #temp
Select 'clos', COUNT(clos.ticket_cp) from clos where CONVERT(date,date) = CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) 

Insert into #temp
Select 'encour', COUNT(en_cours.ticket_cp) from en_cours where CONVERT(date,date) = CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) 

Insert into #temp
Select 'gele', COUNT(gele.ticket_cp) from gele where CONVERT(date,date) = CONVERT(date,GETDATE())

Select * from #temp
Drop table #temp
```

Output

```
Name | Count
clos     | 4
encour | 6
gele      | 2
```

Comment: i want it like this  : nom | count

Comment: I do not get you. How do you want it?

Comment: like i want a column "name" and column "counte" , in column name would be "clos" and the column counte would be "7"  <br/> column name = "encours" column counte "8" ...

Comment: Yes that's exactly the output of my code. Try it out and see :)

Comment: noo listen i want a table with 2 column (name , counte ) in the name would be ("clos , gele , encour) and in the counte would be the count of every one of them

Comment: I have updated the code. Try it out to see if that is the correct output.